# Setting a directory as the dependency directory for a node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm developing two node packages,say A and B.

If A is a dependency of B, is it possible to config node to use A's source directory as the dependency directory for B? (besides using a symlink inside node_moduldes of course). For example by using an npm install option, or a specific node setting.